# make variable accessible to only one another class in same package

Tags: java, android

I have one class which has many variables, I want to make one of the variable accessible by only one another class in same package.

I know this is complicated scenario but is there any way to do like this?

Comment: Not getting u..explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the variable package-private, so any class in the package will have access to it.

You can also provide a reference to that variable in the class you want to have access to it.

More generally, the problem you are facing usually means a design problem. You should try to rethink your architecture: why do you need to have only variable accessible to only an other class? What is special about it and what is special about the classes?

Answer (score 3):

before asking that kind you of question, you should really get some understanding of [java variables visibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

You cannot make a variable "accessible to only one another class". What you can do is creating a getter for it and checking the class the getter was called from, I don't see any sense here however

Answer (score 1):

Understanding that there are many classes in that package, and only one class should be abe to access that variable.

***For what its worth:***

One poor solution would be to add a class in the inheritance hierarchy that is in a separate package. Does not help against malicious programming.

```
package pkg;
class MainClass extends VariableBearer {
    ... variable

package pkg;
class SpecificClass implements VariableUser {
    MainClass main;


package pkg.var {
class VariableBearer extends MainClassParent {
    protected Object variable;

package pkg.var
interface VariableUser
```

Better would be if your specific class has some functional relationship with the main class. That is, the classes are more connected.

Several variations, from inner class to factory method injecting the (private) field.

```
class MainClass {
    private Object variable;

    // Most tight and simple solution: factory with injection
    SpecificClass create() {
        return new SpecificClass(variable);
    }

    class VariableUsage {
    }

class SpecificClass extends VariableUsage {
    ... MainClass.this.variable

class SpecificClass {
    VariableUsage usage = ...
    ... usage.getVariable()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is:

Assuming you have to pass a variable `a` from class `A` to class `B`, use a public getter method inside class `A` to return the value of `a` and call that method inside class `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Best way for example if you want to use variable from X to Y and hope it is a string or any thing else use `Public static YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME` let is in X class so you want to use in Class Y then Type `X.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME` and here you accessed variable from 1 class to another.

Comment: you are using public, so it will be accessible to all the classes but I want to make it accessible by only one class

Comment: but you question is `make-variable-accessible-to-only-one-another-class-in-same-package`

Comment: yes I mentioned **ONLY ONE**

Comment: so just use one variable in class and other variable for other class